# After jquery hover(), css :hover is not ativated on my elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseover

After jquery hover function, css hover does not work.

So, I have several svg elements in my html. 
On these svg elements, I have jquery that if I hover into a button on the bottom all the svg elements will activate the colors to change into yellow (#b8aa85).

At the same time, I want these svg elements to change to white (which I wrote this with css:hover) when I hover onto the svg element itself.

After jquery hover function, the css hover will not work.

Any help needed!

Besides this, in the script I also embed panzoom plugin. is it possible that they crash?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".button").hover(
    function() {
      //mouse over
      $(this).css('color', '#b8aa85');
      $(".col").css('fill', '#b8aa85');
    },
    function() {
      //mouse out
      $(".col").css('fill', "#000000");
      $(this).css('color', "#000000");

    });
});
```

```css
.col {
  fill: "#000000"
}

.col:hover {
  fill: white;
  transition: 0.8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<g id="colony_projects">
  <circle class="col" cx="618" cy="411.2" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="666.8" cy="274.8" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="578.2" cy="493.3" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="577.7" cy="345.2" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="433.8" cy="250.3" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="339.4" cy="464.1" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="658.5" cy="533.4" r="4.1" />
  <circle class="col" cx="540.3" cy="451.6" r="4.1" />
</g>

<div class="colony">
  <div class="button">&#11044;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your css work without the jquery?  I copied your snippet and removed the jquery and it appeared to do nothing.  I then changed your css to `.colony` and put back the jquery and it did both the jquery and the css.  In summary: can't see what the problem is / your jquery and css don't even point to the same thing / the premise in the question title is incorrect as both css and jquery are applied when both css and jquery *point to the same element*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript sets the `color` and `fill` properties *on the element* (which is the same as using a `style` *attribute*.

See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

> count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector

This is specific as you can get and will override any ruleset with a selector.

---

You can hack around it with `!important`, but that is always more trouble than it is worth. You should avoid using the jQuery `hover` method for this (you aren't doing anything with it that you can't do with plain CSS).